# Ensure a div's distance from the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` (e.g. Sign up to get notification). I'd like to put the top portion of the div a certain distance from the bottom of the browser (no matter the size of the size). The goal is that people will see the top of the div and want to scroll down to see the rest of the div. I tried this but the top of the div disappears when I change the size of the browser. My CSS:

```
.divider 
{display:block;
position: absolute;
top: 700px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding:10px
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `margin-bottom` attribute to ensure distance, i.e:

```
.divider 
{
display:block;
position: absolute;
top: 700px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding:10px;
margin-bottom:20px; 
/*change this ^ to the distance you want from the bottom of the page*/
}
```

Or the change the `top` attribute to ensure exact position.

Answer (score 0):

A way with modern CSS3 would be:

```
.divider {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100vh - 10px);
}
```

calc() calculates the display height minus a pixel value. 
Note that the operator must always be surrounded by whitespace.
[More about calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Answer (score 0):

you can put the div inside another and style it like this

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.divider-container {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.divider-container .divider {
    background: #f00 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: -70px; /*visible top portion of the div*/
}
```

```html
<div class="divider-container">
    <div class="divider">
        <h2>Sign up</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```